# Yet another Pig Latin translator

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So I'm trying to code a program with JOptionPane to translate a sentence into pig Latin I have the code mostly figured out but I can seem to get the output when it returns the pig Latin version of the sentence so any help would be tremendous

```
 package piglatin;


 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


 public class Piglatin {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{

  // String to hold input.
  String input;

  // Get a string to convert.
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string and I will convert it to Pig latin.");

  // Convert it to uppercase, for consistency.
  input = input.toUpperCase();



  // Display the Pig Latin translation.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Phrase is: "+ pigLatin);
}

  public class PigLatinator
  {
 private String original; // Original string
 private String pigLatin; // Pig Latin version


 public PigLatinator(String input)
    {
    // Variable to hold each word
    String word;

    // Save the input string.
     original = input;

    // Initialize pigLatin to an empty string.
    pigLatin = "";

    // Trim all leading and trailing whitespaces.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.trim());

    while (sb.length() > 0)
    {
      // Remove the first word from sb and assign it to word.
         word = popWord(sb);

      // Convert the word to Pig Latin and add it to the
      // Pig Latin sentence.
         pigLatin = pigLatin + toPigLatin(word) + " ";
      } 
   }

    private String popWord(StringBuilder sb)
    {
    // Locate the first space, or the end of the string.
    int index = 0;
    while (index < sb.length() && sb.charAt(index) != ' ')
    {
     index++;
    }

  // Get the word from the beginning of sb.
  String word = sb.substring(0, index);

  // Delete the word from sb.
  sb.delete(0, index+1);

  // Return the extracted word.
  return word;
  }

    private String toPigLatin(String word)
  {
  // Create a StringBuilder.
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);

  // Get the first letter of the word.
  char first = sb.charAt(0);

  // Append the letter to the end of the word.
  sb.append(first);

  // Append "AY" to the word.
  sb.append("AY");

  // Delete the first letter.
  sb.deleteCharAt(0);

  // Return the word.
  return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
  getPigLatin method
  @return The Pig Latin version of the string.
   */
   public String getPigLatin()
  {
  return pigLatin;

  }

  /**
  getOriginal method
  @return The original string.
  */
  public String getOriginal()
  {
  return original;
  }
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely specific problem of the question is that the class `PigLatinator` is no where instantiated in the code. One assumes that it should be:

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);

// need to actually use the class
PigLatinator pigLatin = new PigLatinator(input);

// display the results of the PigLatinator's efforts
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Phrase is: "+ pigLatin.getPigLatin());
```

However, the OP code is doing too much work.

- Split the input by using String.split rather than the `popWord` method
- It doesn't seem to account for words that start with a vowel
- Append and delete more work than just appending

Not in the same classes as the OP, but can be re-inserted as desired. This code commented out the input just to allow better debugging, but easily restored.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // String to hold input.
    String input;

    // Get a string to convert.
    // input =
    // JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string and I will convert it to Pig latin.");

    input = "Now is the time for all good people to acquiesce to sleep";

    // debug output
    System.out.println(input);

    // split into worlds
    String[] words = input.split("[\\s]+");

    // the output
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    // process all of the words into pig latin
    for (String word : words) {
        if (output.length() > 0) {
            output.append(" ");
        }
        output.append(toPigLatin(word));
    }

    // show the result
    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Converted is " + output.toString());

    System.out.println(output);
}



static String toPigLatin(final String word)
{
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[aeiouAEIOU].*$");
    final String ay = "ay";
    final String vowel_ay = "yay";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // if the word begins with a vowel, then it is the word + "yay";
    Matcher vowel = pat.matcher(word);
    if (vowel.matches()) {
        sb.append(word);
        sb.append(vowel_ay);
    }
    else if (word.length() > 1) {
        // otherwise, take the first letter, move to the end, and add "ay"
        sb.append(word.substring(1));
        sb.append(word.substring(0, 1));
        sb.append(ay);
    }
    else {
        // just append "ay"
        sb.append(word);
        sb.append(ay);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Example output:

> Now is the time for all good people to acquiesce to sleep
>   owNay isyay hetay imetay orfay allyay oodgay eoplepay otay acquiesceyay otay leepsay

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! It really helped me out to see what the heck I was doing wrong. this code seems to be a lot more elegant and not all over the place.